# How to detect php web page is running within my iPhone App other than Safari

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode

I have built an iPhone app(not iPad) and I am running a webpage within a Web View controller. My question is how can the PHP file detect that it is being run from within this App's UIWebView controller NOT Safari. I want the PHP page to react differently(i.e. get rid of html menu) if run within this app than safari mobile web browser. Is this possible?

WebView Controller

```
#import "AccountViewController.h"

@interface AccountViewController ()

@end

@implementation AccountViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"account" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_AccountWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *sharedHTTPCookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray *cookies = [sharedHTTPCookieStorage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.uniitee.com"]];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [cookies objectEnumerator];
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    while (cookie = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        NSLog(@"COOKIE{name: %@, value: %@}", [cookie name], [cookie value]);
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

PHP FILE

```
<?php require_once('Connections/Uniitee.php'); 

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
{ 
   header('Location: login-m.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load a different URL parameter in the app, such as `?appview=true`, and in the PHP use `if($_GET['appview'])`.

You could then set a session that app view is true to use throughout the users session

Comment: Yes I tried that, but as the website is extensive, there is a risk parameters won't be carried. Is there a solid method to detect?

Comment: I understand that, that's why I advised of using a session to store the information that the user is using the application.

Other than that I don't know of a way that PHP can detect that an app is in use.

Comment: Ok yes i think session would be good, i'll give it a try thanks!