# HTTP request coming from mobile browser or an app?

Tags: php, android, ios

I want to know whether request is coming from Android app, iOS app or any mobile browser.

I'm able to distinguish between an Android app & browser.

I'm using following code to distinguish:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'com.example.user' ){
    $curos='Android';
}
else{
    $curos='Mobile';
}
```

Does iOS make such request? Or does anyone have a better solution?
I need this because I'm using `webView` apps for both Android & iOS platform.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: create you web responsive and use it freely , surely it will work same on all three android iOS and computer / laptop

Comment: You can't trust user-agents, requested with, or any other HTTP header. If you give us your end goal, people can probably give you a better solution.

Comment: @FattiKhan That's not a question here, and I solely says an application. Responsive Web is not a point for an app.

Comment: @user1992200 User agent is able to distinguish between devices, like Android, iPhone & not able to decide whether an app or browser from a device.

Comment: @David My users can simultaneously be logged into four different devices. 1. Android App 2. iOS app 3. Desktop Browser 4. Mobile Browser. For that activity I need to know about where the request is coming from

Comment: Think that user agent will tell it all. And sure you can let apps send any user agent you want. Please show four user agents from your four posibilities.

Comment: `be logged into four different`. You mean `be logged from four different ` ?

Comment: Setup the front end so that they include information about what/who they are when sending the request... so then you can trust it ie.. have ios app add node `'Device' => 'ios'` to each call

Comment: @greenapps Yes be logged in from four different platforms.

Comment: @MattTheNinja That's what I'm trying to get, how would I know that it's from an iOS app so that I can add a node `'Device' => 'ios'`

Comment: Are the app's & websites these requests coming from yours? If so you can amend the requests to include this information?

Comment: Please note that I'm using webview apps for both Android & iOS. So three platforms i.e. Android App, iOS App & mobile website are using same resources & calling same files and all

Comment: @ShanilSoni Did you get any way to detect request is coming from ios app or ios browser? If so please share your experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect php web page is running within my iPhone App other than Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354149/how-to-detect-php-web-page-is-running-within-my-iphone-app-other-than-safari)